# object with only a required field

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have an interface with 2 fields: `featureName`, which is a string, and another `request`, which is an object `{}`.

```
export interface SocketsRequest {
  featureName: string;
  request: {};
}
```

Because I want that `request` field to have a required field `actionType`, I updated the interface and it became:

```
 export interface SocketsRequest {
  featureName: string;
  request: {actionType: string}; // how I can let many other fields here?
 }
```

But now, the problem is that `request` object must have only one field: `actionType`. Else, I'll get an error for incompatible types:

```
const request: SocketsRequest = {
  featureName: 'orders',
  request: {
    actionType: 'all',
    country: 'DE' // country can not be a part of request object
  }
}
```

How can be this solved? thx

Comment: Do you mean `actionType` is optional field in `request`?

Comment: `actionType` is required, the rest are optionals (dynamically builded). Somebody shown a solution from another question and marked this as duplicated. thx